# Redirect www.*.example.com to *.example.com

Tags: ssl, nginx

We have a setup with a wildcard SSL setup for *.example.com so each type a user types
myapp1.example.com
or
myapp5.example.com
or
myappstackoverflow.example.com

Everything is working fine.

However from time to time, some users are typing www.myapp5.example.com adding the www prefix.

I would like to know if there is a way to redirect
www.*.example.com requests to
*.example.com requests

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your certificate is for `*.example.com` only it will not match `whatever.*.example.com`. This means the user will be confronted with a certificate warning before there is even a chance to redirect the user to a different domain.

In other words: what you want is not possible with your current certificate. You would need a certificate which does cover the all the variants your users might enter, i.e. `*.*.example.com`. Only, multi-level wildcard certificates are not possible and thus the most you can do is to get a certificate covering the most common errors of your users but not arbitrary subsub-domains.

Comment: We finally ended up using a wildcard SSL for *.example.com subdomains, but for those that we found out that users were typing something like www.subdomain.example.com we generated their SSL with Let's encrypt